# Why do we use Gradient Descent for Norm Batch since the function has only 2 parameters?

Tags: batch-normalization, theory

[image: Norm Batch formula]

So here is the formula for Z sedile ( gamma * Z + Beta). Since it's a function of 2 parameters why there is still stated in courses that we need to compute gradient descent to find the slope ? Since the slope is exactly ZiNorm for dGamma and 1 for dBeta. It feels like it is overkill since there are only 2 parameters which make finding the slope trivial.